# jQuery CSS selector

Tags: jquery, css

What I want:

Within `$myElement` find all elements with class `.myClass` and attribute `display:none`. Below is what I have tried, I've probably missed something stupid:

`$myElement.find('.myClass[display=none]')`

and

`$myElement.find('.myClass').filter('[display=none]')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `:hidden` pseudo-selector:

```
$myElement.find('.myClass:hidden')
```

The syntax you proposed refers to the attributes of the element, not to the style definitions. In essence, your selector would have matched an element like so:

```
<div class="myClass" display="none">
```

Which doesn't really make much sense.

If you want to be explicit about `display` being "none" (as elements can be hidden [in other ways also](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)), you can use `.filter()`:

```
$myElement.find('.myClass').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('display') == 'none';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use display since that is contained in style and is not an attribute selector.  You can use jQuery's `:visible` pseudo-selector though:

```
$myElement.find('.myClass').not(":visible");
```

jQuery also has a `:hidden` pseudo-selector

```
$myElement.find('.myClass').filter(":hidden");
```

These are implemented by jQuery and not true CSS selectors, so it's best to use find and then filter the result afterwards so you can take advantage of any available `querySelectorAll` benefits

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no selector in jQuery to match rules in the CSS files. However, for this specific case, there is a :visible (which can be combined with :not). It will match all elements that are not visible, which could mean more than simply having display:none, but most probably it's what you are looking for.

See: http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/